# Getting Fingerprint template on my website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, templates, web, fingerprint

I am trying to create a E-voting system. So I am trying to to verify user not only based on his/her document but also based on his fingerprint. While searching regarding this topic I came across a solution that suggested me to store the template generated in BLoB format and then later compare it with input.But how do I make a web API like stuff(similar to accessing requests of microphone and camera for eg. while video call over facebook) so that the user need not have a special software, if this is possible then the issue of sending pre-generated templates as input would be solved as it won't store the template in computer but directly sends it to server.
 
I am totally new to fingerprint.Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am open to further questions and suggestion.

 
 
Problems I need to solve:

- I need to store , retrieve and compare fingerprint template for the voting system.
- Even though I am sending fingerprint template over net it should be safe.
- User need not have a special software to scan and send instead if I could request access to fingerprint scanner through browser.
- Further suggestions, tips, tricks, etc.

Comment: There is no browser API for fingerprint readers.  You can't do that.

Comment: At the moment this cannot be done

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint reader with web API is available with CamsUnit. It provides the Javascript based SDK system which helps reading the fingerprints on the browsers. Check the [API-Documentation](http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html) for more information